# Where to view list of user who logged in using GoogleSignInOptions Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I created an app with GoogleSignInOptions enabled. Now I want to know every user who use this options to log in, but I couldn't find where the data is stored. I try to open **Authentication** menu in https://console.firebase.google.com/ but there is "No users for this project yet".

Where can I view the list of user who logged in using GSO?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve this, is to create a new node in your `Firebase database` named `users`. Every time a user wants to sign-in using `GoogleSignInOptions`, add the desired data there. Your database should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
    |
    ---- users
           |
           ---- user1
           |      |
           |      ---- name: "John"
           |      |
           |      ---- emailAdrress: "john@email.com"
           |
           ---- user2
                  |
                  ---- name: "Mary"
                  |
                  ---- emailAdrress: "mary@email.com"
          //and so on
```

To get the whole list of users, just put a listner on `users` node and query as needed.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So, by default Google didn't store user email who logged in using GSO?

Comment: By default, Google stores the email address in GSO. To get it, you can use this line of code: `String userEmail = googleSignInAccount.getEmail();`. To view all addresses, every time a user wants to sign-in, add the email address as mentioned above.